# Distribution of a Transformation of RV's

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let there be $X, Y$, RV such that the have the joint PDF:

$f(x,y) = 4/(\pi R^2)$, for all $x^2 + y^2 \leq R^2, x<0, y<0$.

Let the constraints above be defined as a set P.

then let $\theta(x,y) = \arctan(Y/X)$, for all $x,y$ in $P$. Find the DF with respect to $\theta$.

I have an idea of have to do this, I had to find the DF with respect to $R$, where $R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$.

My idea right now is to find the area of which $\theta$ covers, and multiply it by the joint PDF to get the DF, obviously with the respective bounds for $\theta$. The question simply asks:

What is $P(\theta \leq a)$, for all $(x,y)$ in $P$? This is where I am stuck. If anyone could help me out it would be appreciated. Also some formatting errors in the question, feel free to tell me my errors

It is also important to mention that I am only looking for a way to find the DF of $\theta$ by the area of the region the probability covers, and without the joint PDF/DF of $R$, and $\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long way:

Well the change of variables transformation would be:

$$f_{X,\Theta}(x, \theta) = {f_{X,Y}(x,x\tan\theta)\begin{Vmatrix}\partial x /\partial x&\partial x/\partial \theta \\ \partial (x\tan\theta)/\partial x&\partial (x\tan\theta)/\partial \theta\end{Vmatrix}}\;\mathbf 1_{x\in[-R;0]\wedge\theta\in[-\pi;\arccos(x/\sqrt R))}$$

Then find the marginal from the joint.

---

The short way:

Alternatively: You can simply observe that the joint of vector $(X,Y)$ is uniform over the quadrant, so the distribution of the angle will be...

Comment: Yes, but I am strictly looking for the DF of $theta$, without finding the joint DF or PDF of the two variables.

Comment: Yes,@FelicioGrande, and how do you find a marginal distribution from a joint distribution?

Comment: I believe you would let the other variable be any value, and that would give the marginal distribution of the first variable? But the question I am trying to solve has 2 parts, and the part you are describing now is the 2nd part (thank you for the advice however). The first part just requires me to look at the area of the probability P($\theta <= a$).

Comment: On reflection, there *is* a much easier way to look at this.  Don't know why I didn't think of it first thing.

Comment: would it be a*$\pi/90$?

Comment: Always measure angles in radians, and the answer should be piecewise for below, inside, and above the support.

Comment: So I have got the piecewise function, 0 if $a<0$, 1 if $a$ < $\pi/2$ rad, and $a*180/(\pi)$ if $0 <= a <= $($\pi$)/2 rad?